# テキストの一番左に追記する方法（python）

Tags: python, python3

下記iperfというツールのログですが、出力結果の一番左に日時を30回づつ追記する
処理を行いたいと思っております。
どの様に、テキストの一番左に追記するのかが分からず悩んでおります。
ご教授いただければと思います。

```
import re

with open('iperf-result.log', 'r', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

#出力したログから、日付部分だけを抽出しリストに保管しておく
date = []
for i, content in enumerate(contents):
    if re.match(r'2021/*.', content):
        print(i, content.strip('\n'))
        date.append(content.strip('\n'))

# 30行で一回分の計測結果がまとめられているため、保存した日付を30回取り出せるか
#試したコード
# for d in date:
#    for i in range(30):
#        print(i, d)

# テキストファイルを追記モードで開く
with open('perf-result.log', 'a', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    write = f.write()
# ここから、どうしたら良いのか。
```

実現したい再集計↓

```
2021/09/0217:15:11.24 2021/09/0217:15:11.24 
2021/09/0217:15:11.24  Connecting to host 192.168.1.1, port 5201
2021/09/0217:15:11.24  [  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 62946 connected to 192.168.1.2 port 5201
2021/09/0217:15:11.24  [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
2021/09/0217:15:11.24  [  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  5.00 MBytes  41.9 Mbits/sec                  
2021/09/0217:15:11.24  [  4]   1.00-2.01   sec  3.25 MBytes  27.0 Mbits/sec                  
2021/09/0217:15:11.24  [  4]   2.01-3.00   sec  15.4 MBytes   130 Mbits/sec
```

生ログ（iperf-result.log）↓

```
2021/09/0217:15:11.24 
Connecting to host 192.168.1.1, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 62946 connected to 192.168.1.2 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  5.00 MBytes  41.9 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   1.00-2.01   sec  3.25 MBytes  27.0 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   2.01-3.00   sec  15.4 MBytes   130 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   3.00-4.01   sec  13.4 MBytes   111 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   4.01-5.02   sec  4.00 MBytes  33.4 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   5.02-6.02   sec  5.75 MBytes  48.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   6.02-7.00   sec  8.88 MBytes  75.7 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  9.62 MBytes  80.5 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   8.00-9.01   sec  20.1 MBytes   168 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   9.01-10.00  sec  11.8 MBytes  98.8 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  10.00-11.01  sec  27.0 MBytes   226 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  11.01-12.00  sec  26.2 MBytes   221 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec  28.1 MBytes   236 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec  29.1 MBytes   244 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec  31.2 MBytes   262 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec  30.1 MBytes   253 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  16.00-17.00  sec  23.8 MBytes   199 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  17.00-18.01  sec  33.0 MBytes   276 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  18.01-19.00  sec  31.9 MBytes   268 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  19.00-20.00  sec  28.1 MBytes   236 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec   386 MBytes   162 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec   386 MBytes   162 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
2021/09/0217:25:00.22 
Connecting to host 192.168.1.1, port 5201
[  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 62946 connected to 192.168.1.2 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-1.00   sec  29.1 MBytes   244 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   1.00-2.00   sec  30.6 MBytes   257 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   2.00-3.00   sec  32.1 MBytes   270 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   3.00-4.00   sec  30.9 MBytes   259 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   4.00-5.00   sec  32.6 MBytes   274 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   5.00-6.00   sec  28.5 MBytes   238 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   6.00-7.00   sec  28.4 MBytes   238 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   7.00-8.00   sec  28.5 MBytes   239 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   8.00-9.00   sec  31.2 MBytes   262 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]   9.00-10.00  sec  33.6 MBytes   283 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  10.00-11.00  sec  31.4 MBytes   262 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  11.00-12.00  sec  32.2 MBytes   272 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  12.00-13.00  sec  31.8 MBytes   266 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  13.00-14.00  sec  31.5 MBytes   265 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  14.00-15.00  sec  33.2 MBytes   278 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  15.00-16.00  sec  32.5 MBytes   272 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  16.00-17.00  sec  29.8 MBytes   250 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  17.00-18.00  sec  27.9 MBytes   233 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  18.00-19.00  sec  25.6 MBytes   215 Mbits/sec                  
[  4]  19.00-20.00  sec  23.8 MBytes   199 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec   605 MBytes   254 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-20.00  sec   605 MBytes   254 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.
```

Comment: ところで実現したい再集計の1行目と2行目以後で挿入される空白の数が違っているのは何か意味や必要があることなのでしょうか？ `2021/09/0217:15:11.24 2021/09/0217:15:11.24 `の`15:11.24 2021/`(1桁の空白)と`2021/09/0217:15:11.24  Connecting to host 192.168.1.1, port 5201`の`15:11.24  Connecting`(2桁の空白)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

行を追いかけながら日付を見つけて記録・更新していくのはどうでしょうか。

```py
DATE_PATTERN = r'\d{4}/[01]\d/[0-3]\d'
TIME_PATTERN = r'[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-6]\d\.\d{2}'


def timestamped_lines(lines):
    timestamp = '????/??/????:??:??.??'
    TIMESTAMP_REGEXP = re.compile(DATE_PATTERN + TIME_PATTERN + r'\s*$')

    for line in lines:
        m = TIMESTAMP_REGEXP.match(line)
        if m:
            timestamp = line.strip()
            sep = ' '
        else:
            sep = '  '
        yield f"{timestamp}{sep}{line}"


with open('perf-result.log', 'a', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    for line in timestamped_lines(contents):
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。if文の処理が、ちょっと理解できておりません。日時にマッチしなかった場合、{timestamp}{sep}{line}"を書き込んでいるということでしょうか？コードを実行させてもらったところ、しっかりと、すべての行の左側に日時が追加されていたもので。理解不足ですみません。

Comment: @sinshin if文の目的は主に、日時にマッチした場合はtimestampを更新し、そうでない場合は更新しないということです。 "{timestamp}{sep}{line}" は(if文の外になるので)どちらの場合でも出力します。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。すいません。「更新」とは、何を言っておられるのでしょうか？本日の日付にしているということではないですよね？

Comment: @sinshin 先のコメントの「更新」は、変数 timestamp に記憶する値(行の左側に挿入される日時)を、日時の形式にマッチした行の内容に書き換えるという意味です

Comment: 何度も、ご返信ありがとうございます。ようやく理解できました。本当にたすかりました。re.compileの使い方も非常に勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

以下は `re.sub()` を使う方法です。

```py
import re

with open('iperf-result.log', 'r') as r, open('perf-result.log', 'w') as w:
  log = re.sub(
    '\n(.+?)\nConnecting to host(.|\n)+?\niperf Done.',
    lambda m: re.sub(r'\n', f'\n{m.group(1)}', m.group(0)),
    '\n' + r.read())
  w.write(log[1:])
```

※ ファイルへの保存は append(`mode='a'`)ではなく write にしています。

**perf-result.log**

```
2021/09/0217:15:11.24 2021/09/0217:15:11.24 
2021/09/0217:15:11.24 Connecting to host 192.168.1.1, port 5201
2021/09/0217:15:11.24 [  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 62946 connected to 192.168.1.2 port 5201
2021/09/0217:15:11.24 [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
                     :

2021/09/0217:15:11.24 
2021/09/0217:15:11.24 iperf Done.
2021/09/0217:25:00.22 2021/09/0217:25:00.22 
2021/09/0217:25:00.22 Connecting to host 192.168.1.1, port 5201
2021/09/0217:25:00.22 [  4] local 192.168.1.1 port 62946 connected to 192.168.1.2 port 5201
2021/09/0217:25:00.22 [ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth
                     :

2021/09/0217:25:00.22 [  4]   0.00-20.00  sec   605 MBytes   254 Mbits/sec                  receiver
2021/09/0217:25:00.22 
2021/09/0217:25:00.22 iperf Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

読み込むファイルが 'iperf-result.log' で追記するファイルが 'perf-result.log' であり別のファイルということですね。
素直に書くのであれば、こんな感じと思います。

```
with open('perf-result.log', 'a', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    for content in contents:
        if content.strip('\n') in date:
            timestamp = date[date.index(content.strip('\n'))]
        f.write(timestamp + ' ' + content)
```

必ず「30行で一回分の計測結果がまとめられている」のであれば次のようにもできます。

```
new_contents = [date[i//30] + ' ' + content for i, content in enumerate(contents)]
with open('perf-result.log', 'a', encoding='shift-jis') as f:
    f.writelines(new_contents)
```